# PySpark: Efficient strategy of splitting my dataframe when writing to a delta table

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I would like to know if there is an efficient strategy to write my Spark dataframe in a delta Table in Datalake.
As a rule of thumb I am splitting the dataframe into some column that has between 70 and 300 different values.

The 'trick' I use to see which column is the candidate to use in the "partitionBy" is the following.
I transform my dataframe into a temporary table and look at the cardinality.

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("my_table")

%sql
select 
    count(distinct(column1)) as column1,
    count(distinct(column2)) as column2,
    ...
from my_table
```

Then I pick the column with a cardinality between 70 - 300, depending on the size of the table
mentally calculating table_size / 128 MB -->is this correct ?

```
df.write.partitionBy("column_candidate")
         .format("delta")
         .mode("overwrite")
         .option("overwriteSchema", "true")
         .save(outputpaht)
```

This method I use does not seem very scientific, and I would like to know if there is a better way to estimate it.I have also seen that there is something called "repartition" but I don't know how to use it or if it is interesting.

How can I calculate the partitions in a more scientific way?

Comment: I'd recommend reading Databricks' best practices page: https://docs.databricks.com/delta/best-practices.html. Things to consider based on that: is your table large enough to benefit from partitioning? Which column is used often in predicates? If this column has high cardinality should I look at OPTIMZE with ZORDER instead? If I have good cardinality is my data evenly distributed?

Comment: You can partition a Delta table by a column. The most commonly used partition column is date. Follow these **two rules of thumb** for deciding on what column to partition by:

If the cardinality of a column will be very high, do not use that column for partitioning. For example, if you partition by a column userId and if there can be 1M distinct user IDs, then that is a bad partitioning strategy.

Amount of data in each partition: You can partition by a column if you expect data in that partition to be at least 1 GB.
I that's what I had instinctively thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of partitions in spark should be decided thoughtfully based on the cluster configuration and requirements of the application. Increasing the number of partitions will make each partition have less data or no data at all. Apache Spark can run a single concurrent task for every partition of an RDD, up to the total number of cores in the cluster. If a cluster has 30 cores then programmers want their RDDs to have 30 cores at the very least or maybe 2 or 3 times of that.

Some acclaimed guidelines for the number of partitions in Spark are as follows-
When the number of partitions is between 100 and 10K partitions based on the size of the cluster and data, the lower and upper bound should be determined.

o   The lower bound for spark partitions is determined by `2 X number of cores` in the cluster available to application.

o   Determining the upper bound for partitions in Spark, the task should take `100+ ms` time to execute. If it takes less time, then the partitioned data might be too small or the application might be spending extra time in scheduling tasks.

For more information Refer this [article](https://www.projectpro.io/article/how-data-partitioning-in-spark-helps-achieve-more-parallelism/297#toc-4)